# php doesn't seem to run the exec command

Tags: php, python, exec

```
  $uploadedFile = $_FILES["files"]["name"];
  $uploadedFile = '"' . $uploadedFile . '"';
  echo $uploadedFile . "<br>";
  exec('/usr/bin/python /path/to/pyscript.py ' . $uploadedFile);
```

I have tried variations on this all to no effect. I have confirmed that the file, $uploadedFile, is being setup correctly. Also, the python script does have the correct permissions. There is noting in the php.ini to indicate that running the exec command is being blocked.

Any constructive help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using shared hosting by any chance?

Comment: Can you try `exec('/usr/bin/python', '/path/to/pyscript.py' . $uploadedFile);` or `exec("/usr/bin/python", "/path/to/pyscript.py" . $uploadedFile);` seems like you may have missed a comma. Also leaving out one of the paths `exec('/usr/bin/python', 'pyscript.py' . $uploadedFile);`

Comment: Are you getting any error? try to look at log files.

Comment: Are you using an unix or windows server ?

Comment: Hi. Just tried that. php -l script.php throws an error saying that only variables can be passed by reference.

Comment: The script is running on a Linux box.

Comment: I am not running on a shared instance.